# Add object in loop from Dictionary to Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I would like to add object from `dictionary` to `array`.

I'm getting info from JSON, and I would like to add in loop these info with two keys and two values : **"name": value1, "imageURL": value2**.

I have 10 items in my loop, so I tried this code, but [] is missing :

```
let urlString = "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=71ad401443f49f22556bb6a31c09d62429323491356d2e829b23f8958fd108c4"
let url = URL(string: urlString)!
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

var arr = [String]()
let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
    // do stuff with response, data & error here
    if let statusesArray = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [[String: Any]] {
        for item in statusesArray! {
            let photos = item["urls"] as? [String: Any]
            let photo = photos?["small"] as? String
            var myDictionary = [
                "name": "test",
                "imageURL": photo]
            for (key, value) in myDictionary {
                arr.append("\(key): \(value)")
            }
        }
        print(arr)
    }
})
```

that gives me this :

```
["imageURL: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479859752262-6f02b79ad6ad?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=a613971b6da0b305154e37bbe01ed833", "name: test", "imageURL: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479859752262-6f02b79ad6ad?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=a613971b6da0b305154e37bbe01ed833", "name: test", "imageURL: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479859752262-6f02b79ad6ad?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=a613971b6da0b305154e37bbe01ed833", "name: test", "imageURL: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479859752262-6f02b79ad6ad?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=a613971b6da0b305154e37bbe01ed833", "name: test", "imageURL: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479859752262-6f02b79ad6ad?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=a613971b6da0b305154e37bbe01ed833", "name: test", "imageURL: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479859752262-6f02b79ad6ad?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=a613971b6da0b305154e37bbe01ed833", "name: test", "imageURL: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479859752262-6f02b79ad6ad?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=a613971b6da0b305154e37bbe01ed833", "name: test", "imageURL: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479859752262-6f02b79ad6ad?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=a613971b6da0b305154e37bbe01ed833", "name: test", "imageURL: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479859752262-6f02b79ad6ad?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=a613971b6da0b305154e37bbe01ed833", "name: test", "imageURL: https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479859752262-6f02b79ad6ad?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=a613971b6da0b305154e37bbe01ed833", "name: test"]
```

Now, I would like to have this (add [] at each object in loop) :

```
[["imageURL": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479859752262-6f02b79ad6ad?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=a613971b6da0b305154e37bbe01ed833", "name": "test"], ["imageURL": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479859752262-6f02b79ad6ad?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=a613971b6da0b305154e37bbe01ed833", "name": "test"], ["imageURL": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479859752262-6f02b79ad6ad?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=a613971b6da0b305154e37bbe01ed833", "name": "test"], ["imageURL": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479859752262-6f02b79ad6ad?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=a613971b6da0b305154e37bbe01ed833", "name": "test"], ["imageURL": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479859752262-6f02b79ad6ad?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=a613971b6da0b305154e37bbe01ed833", "name": "test"], ["imageURL": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1479859752262-6f02b79ad6ad?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&s=a613971b6da0b305154e37bbe01ed833", "name": "test"]]
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Your question makes **no** sense. You say you have a dictionary, but it appears you have a dictionary. You say you want the output to be an array. Your code looks like it builds an array of strings, but your output looks more like a single long string.

Comment: @DuncanC unless i'm misunderstanding, I believe he wants the output to be an array full of dictionaries. Just based on the "I would like to have" text. I could be mistaken though! I often am.

Comment: why don't you just `arr.append(myDictionary)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this part of your code

```
var myDictionary = [
    "name": "test",
    "imageURL": photo]
for (key, value) in myDictionary {
    arr.append("\(key): \(value)")
}
```

**To this**

```
var myDictionary = [
    "name": "test",
    "imageURL": photo]
arr.append(myDictionary)
```

You're adding the dictionary to an array so you have an array full of dictionaries. Each dictionary is a full representation of one of your objects.

**Edit**

declare your array "arr" to hold dictionaries instead of Strings. Just like the error states:

```
var arr = [[String:String]]()
```

Comment: The OP's "arr" variable is declared as an array of strings. That matches the code he posted. Your code would fail since you can't append a dictionary to an array of String objects.

Comment: Cannot convert value of type '[String : String?]' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: Whoops. good catch! That's a pretty easy fix though, just declare the array to hold dictionaries.

Comment: just made an edit. it should hopefully work now, but let me know if there are any other issues.

Comment: @user3353890 thanks man for your help, but again an error : Value of type '[String : String]' has no member 'append'

Comment: That's my mistake. I created a dictionary instead of an array. there should be one more set of bracket there. I'll update now. Moving too fast on my end, sorry!

Comment: Dictionaries don't have an append function, that's why you got the error before. See my updated edit with the additional brackets creating an array of dictionaries.

Comment: @Viny76 did this fix the problem?

Comment: @user3353890 u're good man ! I post another reply on this post, when I print arr in loop that's great, but out from this loop that prints "[]" 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128869/discussion-between-viny76-and-user3353890).